# How to update plugin in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I' m using nopcommerce open source. I want to add the new plugin that already written in below link.

```
http://nopshippingbytotal.codeplex.com/releases/view/93327
```

I add this plugin and it was working fine.now I want to edit this plugin. But I couldn't find out this plugin under the nop -> plugin folder.

How do i edit this plugin in nopcommerce?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the source code, put the whole project folder under NOP_ROOT_FOLDER/Plugins/PLUGIN_FOLDER_NAME. Add the CSPROJ file to your nopCommerce solution (make sure you are downloading the source code version) and you are good to go. :)